# Use NG Repeat to continue printing arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to use ng-repeat to keep adding on to data instead of replacing data?

example (in javascript scope):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myTest', function($scope) {

     var data = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          $scope.data[i] = i;
     }

});
```

example in html:

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myTest">
     <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="x in data"> {{ x }} </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

---

I was hoping for the outcome to be printed like

0
1
2
3
..
.. 
9

---

But I am receiving this outcome

9 (0 will be replace by 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, then 5, .. until 9)

--

Is there a way to stack the numbers instead of keep replacing them in angular?

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see an ngrepeat anywhere.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, as I am new to angular JS and I typed the above code from scratched. I've edited, not sure if it is correct though

Comment: @yubin $scope.data and var data are two different think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update to print the same number: just set that number in the array in the loop like so:

```
data[i] = 1;
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/Lvc0u55v/1895/)

You need to move the `ng-repeat` up to the thing you want to repeat, which to stack the numbers is the `<tr>` tag, also you need to assign the data array to the $scope

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myTest', function($scope) {

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data[i] = i;
  }
  $scope.data = data;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myTest">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: THANKS! This is exactly the output i wanted! thanks!

Comment: may i ask you if I'm able to do a order by clause where by it will print in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var data = [];
```

add

```
$scope.data = [];
```

then instead of

```
$scope.data[i] = i;
```

add

```
$scope.data.push(i);
```

Comment: the second part is fine, it would still work his way

Comment: well, one is a function call and the other is an assignment, but yea I usually push here, I dont know which on is better... they are both constant time as far as I know

Comment: thanks! this works as well! I'm still trying to understand this though

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want to achieve ? I assigned the table to the scope after the for loop and it seems to work.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myTest', function($scope) {

     var data = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          data[i] = i;
     }
     $scope.data = data; 
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myTest">
     <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
          <td> {{ x }} </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I have more or less understood how you done it!

Comment: May I ask, is there any ways to print the same character over? as it seems to me like, if I wanted to print

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

it will not work.